# Why is my program outputing the results twice in a row?

Tags: java, arrays

I'm in the process of making a program that can take the #'s from a credit card and check to see if it's valid.

here is my code so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner reader=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter your credit card #");
        String Ccard=reader.nextLine();
        int length=Ccard.length();
        doubleDig(Ccard,length);
        int []digits=doubleDig(Ccard,length);
        /*for(int x=0;x<digits.length;x++){
        System.out.println(digits[x]);
        }test array*/

    }
    public static int[] doubleDig(String cardNum,int length){
        int []nums=new int[length];
        for(int x=0;x<cardNum.length();x++){
            nums[x]=cardNum.charAt(x);
            System.out.println(cardNum.charAt(x));
        }//makes array
        //System.out.println(nums.length);
        for(int x=nums.length;x<0;x-=2){
            nums[x]=nums[x]*2;
        }
        return nums;

    }//end doubleDig
}
```

I went to see if the array was set up correctly so I used:
`System.out.println(nums[x]);`   in the loop but got values that I didn't understand. I then went and used: 
`System.out.println(cardNum.charAt(x));`  in the loop to see what was up.
I then noticed that the array was somehow being displayed a 2nd time. The size of the array should be equal to the length of the string the user put in (I'm using 5491946915444920 as my test value), which is 16 in this case. 16 numbers display, but then it loops over itself again somehow and the values display a 2nd time(displaying 32 total #'s). Any clues?

Comment: because you're calling `doubleDig` twice?

Comment: What do you mean exactly? is the duplication coming from `int []digits=doubleDig(Ccard,length);` as well as `doubleDig(Ccard,length);`?

Comment: I think you are trying to execute the doubleDig() method first and then trying to get the array of digits. So when you call this method two times the System.out.println executes, thought the method called for different purposes.

Comment: As a general rule, never print inside of "worker functions" (unless of course you're debugging). Return the result, then let the caller print it if they want.

Comment: oh, i see what you mean, thanks for that. now i dont know if it's best to make a separate question or just ask it here, but ill just ask it here for now. So when i originally had `System.out.println(nums[x]);`, the values i got were not what i expected 5,4,9,1,ect. to show up, but got completely different values. how did those values get calculated?

Comment: Here is what happens: I expect to see 5,4,9,1 as the first batch of digits, but instead i see 53,52,57,49.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this:

```
public static int[] doubleDig(String cardNum, int length) {
    int[] nums = new int[length];
    int num;
    for (int x = 0; x < cardNum.length(); x++) {
        nums[x]=Integer.parseInt(cardNum.substring(x, x+1));
    }
    System.out.println(nums.length);
    return nums;
}
```

Comment: thank you, and thank you david for explaining the what i ended up doing when i used `.charAt()`. I should be able to get the rest of the program made without much difficulty(hopefully).

Answer (score 1):

Because at this line of code `nums[x] = cardNum.charAt(x);`  you are actually printing char values i.e [53, 52, 57,etc] for 5491946915444920

Comment: Oh, ok. that makes sense. how would i go about getting the actual numbers then if `.charAt()` doesn't work?